# Vuefire get Firebase Image Url

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, firebase-storage, vuefire

I am storing relative paths to images in my firebase database for each item I wish to display.  I am having trouble getting the images to appear on the screen, as I need to get the images asynchronously.  The firebase schema is currently as follows:

```
{
  items: {
    <id#1>: {
      image_loc: ...,
    },
    <id#2>: {
      image_loc: ...,
    },
  }
}
```

I would like to display each of these images on my page with code such as:

```vue
<div v-for="item in items">
  <img v-bind:src="item.image_loc">
</div>
```

This does not work, as my relative location points to a place in firebase storage.  The relavent code to get the true url from this relative url is:

```js
firebase.storage().ref('items').child(<the_image_loc>).getDownloadURL()
```

which returns a promise with the true url.  Here is my current vue.js code:

```js
var vue = new Vue({
  el: '.barba-container',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  firebase: function() {
    return {
      items: firebase.database().ref().child('items'),
    };
  }
});
```

I have tried using computed properties, including the use of vue-async-computed, but these solutions do not seem to work as I cannot pass in parameters.

Basically, how do I display a list of elements where each element needs the result of a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the asyncComputed library for vue.js and by making a promise to download all images at once, instead of trying to do so individually.

```js
/**
 * Returns a promise that resolves when an item has all async properties set
 */
function VotingItem(item) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    item.short_description = item.description.slice(0, 140).concat('...');

    if (item.image_loc === undefined) {
      resolve(item);
    }
    firebase.storage().ref("items").child(item.image_loc).getDownloadURL()
      .then(function(url) {
        item.image_url = url;
        resolve(item); 
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        item.image_url = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150";
        resolve(item);
      });   
  });  
  return promise;
}

var vue = new Vue({
  el: '.barba-container',
  data: {
    items: [],
    is_loading: false
  },
  firebase: function() {
    return {
      items: firebase.database().ref().child('items'),
    };
  },
  asyncComputed: {
    processedItems: {
      get: function() {
        var promises = this.items.map(VotingItem);
        return Promise.all(promises);
      },
      default: []
    }
  }
});
```

Lastly, I needed to use: `v-for="item in processedItems"` in my template to render the items with image urls attached

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it without any extra dependencies not adding elements to the array until the url is resolved:

in my template:

```
<div v-for="foo in foos" :key="foo.bar">
  <img :src="foo.src" :alt="foo.anotherbar">
  ...
</div>
```

in my component (for example inside `mounted()`)

```
const db = firebase.firestore()
const storage = firebase.storage().ref()
const _this = this

db.collection('foos').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  const foos = []
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    foos.push(doc.data())
  })
  return Promise.all(foos.map(foo => {
    return storage.child(foo.imagePath).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      foo.src = url
       _this.foos.push(foo)
    })
  }))
}).then(() => {
  console.log('all loaded')    
})
```